# Using a remote /etc/hosts to ping myself

Tags: dns

Can i use a remote /etc/hosts file to redirect the ping to my own computer i.e. my /etc/hosts file does not have the entry but the only other computer conncted vua ethernet has the entry.Is it possible.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is ambiguous.

If are asking whether you can cause your machine to ping itself by changing the "/etc/hosts" file on the remote machine the answer is "No you can't".

- When you execute the ping command on your machine, the first thing it does is to resolve the hostname you are pinging to an IP address.  This is typically done by looking in the *local* "/etc/hosts" file and/or DNS.  The remote machine's "/etc/hosts" file is not consulted.
- Then the "ping" command sends an ICMP packet to the IP address that the hostname resolved to.  At no point is there any further translation of the hostname, either locally or on the host that the packet goes to.  The ICMP packet only contains IP addresses.

---

If you are asking whether you can change your local "/etc/hosts" make your host ping itself when it *thinks* it is talking to another machine, the answer is "Yes ... sort of".  You *can* make the remote hostname resolve to the IP address of your machine.

However:

- If you do that, *all* requests to that hostname from your host will end up talking to your machine ... which unlikely to be a desirable state of affairs.
- The ICMP packets that "ping" sends will probably be reflected locally without the packets making it onto your local network.  That means that you "ping" won't tell you much about how the network is working.

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out the same thing.
I also put the question in a different format on SO but i am now quite sure it cannot be done and if possible is worth no use.
Thnx for the answers though.

The reason for asking the question is you can refer to my other zeroconf network asked about the .local thing.

Thnx Anyway.